# Problem on Straight lines

Tags: geometry

I am working on this question.
A light ray coming along the line $3x+4y=5$ , gets reflected from the line $ax+by=1$ and goes along the line $5x-12y =10$. Now, I have to find out the value of $a$ and $b$ .
I have calculated the value of $x$ and $y$ by equating $x+4y=5$  and $5x-12y =10$. I have put the values of $x$ and $y$ in the equation $ax+by=1$  and got the first equation in terms of $a$ and $b$.
Now the problem is that i am unable to find out the second equation in terms of $a$ and $b$. I think I have to equate either of the two equation containing $x$ and $y$ terms with the one having $a$ and $b$ terms but I am unable to get any equation. I am stuck up in lengthy calculations ! Please help.

Comment: A normal to the desired line must be bisector of the given lines directing vectors, i.e. $\displaystyle\left(-\frac{4}{5};\frac{3}{5}\right)\pm \left(\frac{12}{13};\frac{5}{13}\right) = (a,b)$ . It's not too hard to prove that bisector of vectors $a,b$ is $\frac{a}{||a||}+\frac{b}{||b||}$.

Comment: Yes, I know we can also solve this question with the bisector method but i am trying it to solve it with the other method and i am unable to form the second equation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the mirrors can be any of the two bisectors of the lines $$3x+4y = 5, 5x - 12y = 10.$$ they are given by $$\frac{3x+4y - 5}{5} = \pm \frac{5x-12y - 10}{13}\tag 1$$ this simplifies to $$14x+112y-15 = 0, 64x-8y-115=0 \tag 2$$ these are equivalent to $$ \frac{14}{15}x+\frac{112}{15}y = 1, \frac{64}{115}x-\frac{8}{115}y=1 \tag 3$$

therefore, there are two choices for the pair $(a,b)$:$$  a = \frac{14}{15}, b = \frac{112}{15} \text{ or } a = \frac{64}{115}, b = -\frac{8}{115}.$$

Comment: Thank you ! Could you please explain how did you get the values for a and b after the 3rd step . If i solve these two equation i will get the values for x and y and if i put those values in ax+by=1 , i will get only one equation in terms of a and b . How will i get the second equation . I am unable to get that

Comment: @Nancy, you mean how i go from $(2)$ to $(3)?$  i divided the first equation by $15$ and the second one by $115.$

Comment: No , I mean by solving 14x+112y-15=0 and 64x-8y-115 , we will get the values of x and y . How do I find a and b ?

Comment: @Nancy, you don't need to solve those equations. you are to find the number that multiply $x$ and $y$ so that you can put it in the form $ax+by = 1.$  this is another standard from of a line just as $y = mx + c$ is.

Comment: Okayy !!! Now , I understood . Thank you very much . Great answer !

Answer (score 1):

Solve the equations of the lines: $3x+4y=5$ & $5x-12y=10$ to obtain the point of intersection as $\left(\frac{25}{14}, \frac{-5}{56}\right)$. Then set the coordinates of this point in the equation of the line: $ax+by=1$ acting as reflector, we get $$\left(\frac{25}{14}\right)a+\left(\frac{-5}{56}\right)b=1 \implies100a-5b=56 $$$$ b=\frac{100a-56}{5} \tag 1$$ Now, for the line: $ax+by=1$ (having slope $\frac{-a}{b}$) to be reflector for the lines $3x+4y=5$ (having slope $\frac{-3}{4}$) & $5x-12y=10$ (having slope $\frac{5}{12}$) the condition is that $$\text{angle between first & second lines}=\text{angle between first & third lines}$$ Thus, we have $$\tan\left|\frac{\left(\frac{-a}{b}\right)-\left(\frac{-3}{4}\right)}{1+\left(\frac{-a}{b}\right)\left(\frac{-3}{4}\right)}\right|=\tan\left|\frac{\left(\frac{-a}{b}\right)-\left(\frac{5}{12}\right)}{1+\left(\frac{-a}{b}\right)\left(\frac{5}{12}\right)}\right|$$
 $$\implies \left|\frac{-4a+3b}{3a+4b}\right|=\left|\frac{12a+5b}{5a-12b}\right|$$ Now, set the value of $b$ from the eq(1) in above expression, we get $$\left|\frac{-4a+\frac{3}{5}(100a-56)}{3a+\frac{4}{5}(100a-56)}\right|=\left|\frac{12a+\frac{5}{5}(100a-56)}{5a-\frac{12}{5}(100a-56)}\right|$$ $$\left|\frac{280a-168}{415a-224}\right|=\left|\frac{560a-280}{-1175a+672}\right| \tag 2$$
$$\implies (280a-168)(-1175a+672)=(415a-224)(560a-280)$$ by simplifying the above expression, we get a quadratic equation in terms of $a$ as follows $$96600a^2-143920a+50176=0 \implies a=\frac{14}{15} \space \text{&} \space \frac{64}{115} $$ These values duly satisfy the original eq(2) hence by setting the above two values of $a$ in the eq(1), we get corresponding two values of $b$ as follows $$a=\frac{14}{15} \implies b=\frac{100\left(\frac{14}{15}\right)-56}{5}=\frac{112}{15}$$ and $$a=\frac{64}{115} \implies b=\frac{100\left(\frac{64}{115}\right)-56}{5}=\frac{-8}{115}$$ The above two sets of the values of $a$ & $b$ represents that the reflector line: $ax+by=1$ is the bisector of either acute angle or obtuse angle between the lines: $3x+4y=5$ & $5x-12y=10$. Since, the direction of reflection is not mentioned in the question hence we get two sets of values of $a$ & $b$ corresponding to two perpendicular reflecting lines: $ax+by=1$ as follows 
$$\left(a=\frac{14}{15}, b=\frac{112}{15}\right)\space \text{&} \space \left(a=\frac{64}{115}, b=\frac{-8}{115}\right)$$

Comment: you really know how to complicate things, don't you?

Comment: Thank you but my book says the correct answer is a= \frac{64}{115} and b = \frac{-8}{115}

Comment: @abel Sir kindly tell us an easier way.

Comment: Yes please tell us an easier way . Thank you !

Comment: @Nancy, Note that $\frac{448}{805} = \frac{64}{115}$ and $\frac{-56}{805} = \frac{-8}{115}$.

Comment: Oops ! I am so sorry for this mistake .